# While importing gmail contact by using jquery getting ("Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

While importing google contact by using jQuery I get the following error

> ("Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined)

I see that error after the first 24 results are fetched. Below is my code

```
for( var i= 0 ; i < response.feed.entry.length ; i++) {
   email[i] = response.feed.entry[i].gd$email[0].address;
```

Comment: `gd$email` is undefined. So that entry probably does not have an email associated with it.

Comment: First check by weather index 0 is set or not by using if (response.feed.entry[i] !== undefined && response.feed.entry[i].gd$email[0] !== undefined) { .... }

Answer (score 0):

```
response.feed.entry = [
     {gd$email:[
        {address: 'xyz'}
     ]},
     {gd$email:[
        {address: 'xyz'}
     ]} 

 ]
```

After 23rd index there should not be any 'gd$email' property.